# Remove list item permissions by role type using JSOM

Tags: javascript, permissions, splistitem, jsom

I'm looking for a good way to remove all list item permissions on a certain list item of a specific role type using the JavaScript object model.

With `myListItem.get_roleAssignments().getByPrincipal(myUser).deleteObject();` I can delete the permission for a certain user. I'm looking for a way to delete all permissions of a certain role type (eg SP.RoleType.contributor).

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can think of is this pseudocode:

1. foreach roleAssignment 'rA'
2. foreach roleDefinitionBinding 'rDb' in rA.get_roleDefinitionBindings()
3. Check if user has the base permissions associated with the contributor role by repeatedly using rDb.has(...) which checks for a base permission
4. if true, delete current roleAssignment from listItem

An example of the check in 3:
if(rDb.has(SP.PermissionKind.editListItems) && rDb.Has(...) && ...). The relation between permission level (Contributor) and its permissions can be found somewhere in the settings of your site collection, or [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Permission-levels-and-permissions-49d456eb-d3c8-4402-86b1-deb911224afb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). The SP.PermissionKind enumeration can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556747(v=office.14).aspx).